# Apache CXF web services. Slow init of the server

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I am developing web services with [Apache CXF 2.7.8](http://cxf.apache.org/cxf-278-release-notes.html). I use wsdl2java to generate the [SEI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endpoint_interface) and the implementations. There are hundreds of web service endpoints.

I use the embedded jetty.

When the server is started it takes hours to initialize every endpoint.

I used to publish the endpoints with [Endpoint.publish(address, implementor)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Endpoint.html#publish%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method, but I found this way a JAXBContext instance is created for every service. I fixed that using single JAXBContext instance for each service and it helped.

But still, starting the server is really slow.

In the logs this fragment is repeated hundreds of times.

> cl: AbstractObservable m: setMessageObserver [main] 20:50:48 DEBUG - Accept: */*
>
> cl: Headers m: logProtocolHeaders [main] 20:50:48 DEBUG - No Trust Decider for Conduit '{http://cxf.apache.org}TransportURIResolver.http-conduit'. An afirmative Trust Decision is assumed.
>
> cl: HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream m: makeTrustDecision [main] 20:50:48 DEBUG - Conduit '{http://cxf.apache.org}TransportURIResolver.http-conduit' has been (re)configured for plain http.
>
> cl: HTTPConduit m: setTlsClientParameters [main] 20:50:48 DEBUG - No Trust Decider configured for Conduit '{http://cxf.apache.org}TransportURIResolver.http-conduit'
>
> cl: HTTPConduit m: logConfig [main] 20:50:48 DEBUG - No Auth Supplier configured for Conduit '{http://cxf.apache.org}TransportURIResolver.http-conduit'
>
> cl: HTTPConduit m: logConfig [main] 20:50:48 DEBUG - Conduit '{http://cxf.apache.org}TransportURIResolver.http-conduit' has been configured for plain http.
>
> cl: HTTPConduit m: logConfig [main] 20:50:48 DEBUG - registering incoming observer: org.apache.cxf.transport.TransportURIResolver$1@1405d451

Can anyone explain what this means ? And if there is some way to configure these settings globally just once ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This means you are using an HTTP (or worse: https) URL for something, likely WSDL locations.   Thus, for every WSDL/schema/etc.... it has to download those from the the remote location.   For faster startup, put the wsdl's local and reference them directly.

Comment: I have my wsdl on the classpath. Every ws implementation is anotated with @WebService(...,wsdlLocation="classpath:myWsdl.wsdl",..). Despite that when i access some of the exposed WS and require the wsdl (?wsdl) i get different wsdl from what's on the classpath (it is providing the same information, but it is not the same file, it looks different). What am i supposed to do ? I tried using "local/MyWS" instead of "http://localhost:8080/MyWS" but again the log says that the service is deployd on http://localhost:8080/MyWS.
Thank you :).